# Lower order perturbations of 2nd order differential operators

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the well-known Hormander's sum of squares $P = \sum_{j = 1}^m X_j^2$, where $X_j$ are vector fields on a compact manifold $M$ of dimension $n$. Also assume, as is usual to this theory, $m < n$ and the brackets of the $X_j$'s yield the full tangent space of $M$ at each point. My question is: if we now add a lower order perturbation, that is consider $Q = P - i\beta X$, where $X$ is a vector field on $M, 
\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, will $Q$ be still self-adjoint? Does it matter whether $X = X_j$, for one of the given $X_j$'s?

Edit (after Willie Wong and Nate Eldredge's comments): If we assume that $i\beta X$ also commutes with $P$, does that help?

Comment: Typically, not unless you change the measure in just the right way.  Almost anything you try will be a counterexample.

Comment: @NateEldredge Could you please elaborate a little? Particularly on "change the measure in just the right way"? Thanks.

Comment: As an analogy in the elliptic setting, $P = d^2/dx^2$ is self-adjoint on $L^2(\mathbb{R}, dx)$ but $Q = d^2/dx^2 + d/dx$ is not (its adjoint is $d^2/dx^2 - d/dx$).  However, $Q$ is self-adjoint on $L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^{-x} dx)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I understand. Is there any way of saying that it would work if the perturbation is "small enough"? Maybe something like relatively bounded perturbation? I looked up the Kato-Rellich theorem, but can we infer more than Kato-Rellich if the operators under consideration are differential operators, and the perturbation is relatively bounded and smaller order?

Comment: The problem is more fundamental than that.  In Kato-Rellich the perturbation is at least symmetric, and the problem is to sort out the domain of the adjoint.  An example is something like a second order operator perturbed by a zero order term.  Here your perturbation is not even symmetric: integration by parts suggests that formally $(\beta X)^* = -\beta X + V$ for some zero-order term (potential) $V$.  It's more likely to be skew symmetric.

Comment: Thinking in terms of spectra, self-adjoint operators tend to behave like real numbers, and skew-adjoint operators are imaginary numbers.  It's a little like asking "if I take a real number, and add a very small imaginary number, might the result turn out to be real?"  No, it never will.

Comment: If this is question is about whether the operator is formally self-adjoint, you should be able to do the calculation yourself.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have edited the question, thanks!

Comment: @rookie: as Deane Yang said, you can just compute. But let me give you an example. Take $M = \mathbb{S}^1$ and take $P = d^2 / d\theta^2$ the Laplacian. Take $X = \sin(\theta) d/d\theta$. For any $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ the operator $Q$ as you defined it is not self-adjoint relative to the standard measure.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question further

Comment: @NateEldredge I have edited the question further, thanks...